# TFS Custom WorkItemType Set field to current user

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I'm trying to add a custom workitemtype to TFS.

I would like to have a field called SignOff, with possible values of Yes/No.  Next to that I would like to have a field called SignOffBy - when you change the SignOff field the SignOffBy field should be set to the current user.

```xml
<FIELD name="Signoff" refname="MyProj.Signoff" type="String">
    <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
        <LISTITEM value="Yes" />
        <LISTITEM value="No" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
    <DEFAULT from="value" value="No" />
</FIELD>
<FIELD name="Signoff By" refname="MyProj.SignoffBy" type="String">
    <WHENCHANGED field="MyProj.Signoff">
        <DEFAULT from="currentuser" />
    </WHENCHANGED>
    <WHENNOTCHANGED field="MyProj.SsoSignoff">
        <READONLY />
        <EMPTY />
    </WHENNOTCHANGED>
</FIELD>
```

The problem seems to be that the SignOffBy field wants to be populated at all times.  If I don't use the empty tag it just gets populated right away.  I want it to be blank, but only get populated when the field gets changed.  At the moment it's not changing at all - it's just blank and stays blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of onchanged rules, have a WHEN rule for signoff being false, and set the field to EMPTY/READONLY as you currently do.
Have a second WHEN rule for the true case, and use a COPY rule to copy the *currentuser* value into the field instead of doing it via a DEFAULT rule.

Comment: Already figured this out, but I did exactly what you suggested.  Thanks